# An—most likely—if function isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

This thing I'm trying to do seems simpler than eating a cake. Yet, it just *does not work*!

First, I'll post the JavaScript code so that you can understand what I'm talking about:

```
var opIndex = 0;

$("#CCT").click(function(){
    opIndex = 1;
});
$("#CCO").click(function(){
    opIndex = 0;
});

if (opIndex == 0) {
    $("#CCO").css("display", "none");
    $("#CCT").css("display", "table");
};
if (opIndex == 1) {
    $("#CCO").css("display", "table");
    $("#CCT").css("display", "none");
};
```

You might be wondering why I'm not using `else` instead of another `if`, but I have my reasons for the future. That said, I tried that too. Didn't work either.
That aside, both `#CCO` and `#CCT` are `divs` with `display: table` and inside them are `divs` with `display: table-cell`, which I'm vertically aligning. Here's the HTML code, if necessary:

```
<div class="controlzCont" id="CCO">
    <div class="controlzH" id="prevH">
        <img src="../images/icons/black/prev.png" width="100%" alt="Prev" class="arrowB" id="prevImg">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="controlzCont" id="CCT">
    <div class="controlzH" id="nextH">
        <img src="../images/icons/black/next.png" width="100%" alt="Prev" class="arrowB" id="nextImg">
    </div>
</div>
```

I checked if the click wasn't registering, but that wasn't the fault. I called a function on click that I created outside. It `alerted` me the `opIndex`. It worked.

Then, I tried `alerting` the `opIndex` from within the `if` function. Since originally, the `opIndex` is 0, the `if (opIndex == 0)` function `alerted` me that on page load.

I don't even really understand *what* the issue is, much less how to fix it.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the conditional code is outside the click event handler ... changing optIndex in those click events wont run the code outside the click function. Javascript doesn't work that way

Comment: You've written those `if` statements as if they were `when` statements. There is no such animal in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statements only execute once the way you have it. Perhaps the following would suit?

```
$("#CCT").click(function(){
    $("#CCO").css("display", "table");
    $("#CCT").css("display", "none");
});

$("#CCO").click(function(){
    $("#CCO").css("display", "none");
    $("#CCT").css("display", "table");
});
```

Perhaps a simpler implementation would declare the display CSS separately, and use the following:

```
$(".controlzCont").click(function() {
    $(".controlzCont").show();
    $(this).hide();
})
```

Comment: I see. That would work, but I have some other things planned where I'll need that var. Although, your answer gave me an idea on how to fix this. Actually, the updated answer of yours is quite helpful. Still, as I said, I need those vars. Someone posted an answer that I was able to read, and it worked perfectly, but for some reason, they deleted it right afterwards. Thanks, though, that answer of yours partially solves my problem, and definitely solves what I've given on here, so unless a much better answer is given or that previous answer is reposted, I'll mark this one as accepted when I can.

Comment: If you need the var for something else, you can add it in to the first example very easily just like you have it in your question. The second example is not as easy to do so